# JTextField input validation with matcher regex doesn't match when application runs outside IDE (Netbeans)

Tags: java, regex, netbeans, jtextfield

I programmed a Java desktop application under linux and everything works well. Now I would like to create a package to deploy it for windows users. In the application I used Matcher class to validate a JTextField and under linux it runs well either when I run from Netbeans IDE and from command line with "java -jar". On Windows it runs too, but only from the IDE. When i cd from the prompt and launch "java -jar" it starts normally but JTextField validation doesn't recognize input. I'm sure I'm using the same JDK for both modes. May be an encoding issue? I tried to encode files differently and obviously every time I recompile also clean *.class files compiled before. Regex are written in source files, not read from file.

Comment: The same with eclipse.

Comment: Using jdk 1.7 or 1.8 is the same.

Comment: Solved... so and so, using Hibernate Validation. Now it runs but the question remains: why?